# How can I limit access to a set of authorized users in Azure Mobile Services?

Tags: azure-mobile-services

If I add authentication in Azure Mobile Service with Google as the provider, I go and create an app, get the app_id and secret and plug it in. Great, now users can authenticate with google and get a user token. Now they are considered an "authenticated user" wrt the table permissions.

However, I don't want to authorize everyone with a google account access to my API. Is it possible to limit this to a list of known users? Must I check every request for specific user ids?

Perhaps social login is not the best choice here and I should use something else like Azure AD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use Azure Active Directory to solve this problem. This way, I can create users in Azure AD but not have to manage users myself in the back end. With this choice I am still able to chose the only authenticated users permission level without having to check on every rest endpoint that the authentication users is one of the ones I want to grant access to.

Answer (score 1):

We added custom authentication provider to wams and synchronize the social account with "our" user-account that is stored in the database. For protected web api methods a user account needs to be activated first. You have to check manually whether an account is activated/ high privileged or not and return the result or unauthorized status code.

Comment: Yes, I was hoping to have to avoid putting a call in every script. I was wondering if there was someway to inject a middleware type layer to do this in one place, rather than every script.